# Why does Robocopy work once and then ignore all files the next time?

Tags: windows, robocopy

I used the following command:

```
Robocopy c:\source c:\backup /MIR /XD .svn
```

Then I deleted `c:\backup` and did it once again. This time it ignored all files and copied nothing.
Why is that?

How do I force Robocopy to copy all the files again?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. If I delete the backup dir and run robocopy again, it will do the copy again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess that the /MIR is assuming that the files are already there and not checking again. Maybe include the /FFT switch as well which uses timestamps for comparison and see if it makes a difference.

Alternatively let robocopy log what it is doing. The log file may reveal why it is currently *skipping* files or folders. I would use the following for troubleshooting:

> Robocopy c:\source c:\backup /MIR /V /LOG:WhySkip.txt  /XD .svn

Added:
/V - Verbose listing including skipped files
/LOG:file - Log output to file

Comment: Well I changed the target directory so that it works.